# Unable to insert date data into oracle table

Tags: oracle

Unable to insert date data into oracle table. Please find the below query and error

**Query:**

```
INSERT INTO TEST.SUPPLIER
(SUPPLIER_ID, SUPPLIER_NAME, CONTACT_NAME, DOB)
VALUES(6, 'rr', 'ss','2019-06-19');
```

**Error:**

> SQL Error [1843] [22008]: ORA-01843: not a valid month
>   VALUES(6, 'rr', 'ss','2019-06-19'), Error Msg = ORA-01843: not a valid month
>     ORA-01843: not a valid month

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try the below query:

```
INSERT INTO TEST.SUPPLIER (SUPPLIER_ID, SUPPLIER_NAME, CONTACT_NAME, DOB) VALUES(6, 'rr', 'ss',DATE '2019-06-19');**
```

`DATE` keyword interprets the following string as a date.

Comment: Excellent answer! Always use the date constant `DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd'`. It works every time, regardless of date format settings :)

Comment: Agreed, for some strange reason the correct syntax for writing a [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm) in Oracle is not widely known, even among experienced developers.

Answer (score 1):

- I am sure you would have used DOB as date when defining the table.
- You may directly enter date in `DD/MON/YYYY` format, with MON as first three letters of month.
- To format date to `YYYY-MM-DD` format, you may use `DATE` before the string which will look like `DATE '2019-07-20'`

Here's a quick run through for all the points

```
create table supplier(SUPPLIER_ID number, SUPPLIER_NAME varchar2(20), CONTACT_NAME varchar2(20), DOB date);

insert into supplier values(12, 'supplier1', 'contact1', '18/JAN/2019');
insert into supplier values(13, 'supplier2', 'contact2', date '2019-07-20');

select * from supplier;
```

```
SUPPLIER_ID SUPPLIER_NAME        CONTACT_NAME         DOB
----------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------
         12 supplier1            contact1             18-JAN-19
         13 supplier2            contact2             20-JUL-19
```

Hope it sorts!

Comment: double asterisks don't work as **bold** inside a code section. (Also, trailing backticks appear, supposedly an attempt to make `**bold**` work?)

Comment: "*You may directly enter date in DD/MON/YYYY format*" - no, you may **not**. It might work on your computer, but it definitely won't work on my computer.  The format that is recognized is defined by the locale settings of the client application connecting to the Oracle server. It's not defined by the server, nor is there a "universal" format that works across all installations. The ISO format ( `date '...'`) or an explicit `to_char()` call (with a month **number**, not a name) are the only safe ways to specify a date value

Comment: @ShinTakezou It was marked bold to highlight and not use in function. Thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for sharing. Noted. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to covert your date string to `DATE` type. Before inserting the value

```
INSERT INTO TEST.SUPPLIER (SUPPLIER_ID, SUPPLIER_NAME, CONTACT_NAME, DOB) 
VALUES(6, 'rr', 'ss',TO_DATE('2003/05/03', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))
```